# array join string Invalid string length (5 million data)

Tags: javascript, node.js

My code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const desktopDir = path.join(os.homedir(), "Desktop");

var F_HASH = "........";
var F_AMOUNT = 5000000; //number of data

var game_res = [];

for (var i = 1; i < F_AMOUNT+1; i++) {        
    /*.................code
    .............................    
    ..................................*/
    game_res.push(/*..............code...............*/);  //(/r/n)       
}     
     
var h_row = i-1;
h_row = h_row.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    
game_res = game_res.join(''); 
    
fs.writeFileSync(desktopDir + "/" + "Latest " + h_row + " hash.txt", game_res);
```

Text file output looks like this:

```
xxxxxxxxxxhashxxxxxxxxxx 0.00
xxxxxxxxxxhashxxxxxxxxxx 0.00
xxxxxxxxxxhashxxxxxxxxxx 0.00
xxxxxxxxxxhashxxxxxxxxxx 0.00
```

i set F_AMOUNT to 1,000,000 it works fine, no error

but when i set F_AMOUNT to 5,000,000 error show up like this:

```
****DIR*****\****file****.js:34
game_res = game_res.join('');
                    ^

RangeError: Invalid string length
    at Array.join (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (****DIR*****\****file****.js:34:21)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m
```

i set "node_options max-old-space-size" to 10240
but nothing happen, still give me error
[image]

real data:
[image]

Comment: How large is each element?  If you have 100 characters in each string, then you are creating more than a gigabyte of strings, and you'd need space both for the list and for the joined string.

Comment: @TimRoberts 75 characters for each string sir, 1 mil data is 73-74 MB

Comment: How much RAM do you have on the machine you are running this on?

Comment: @WMRamadan 16GB sir

Comment: Are you sure the string length for each element is 75 characters? I can't reproduce the issue with that string length. I don't think the issue is running out of memory, I think the issue is running into the maximum string length that V8 allows, which is about 1GB.

Comment: @robertklep i just updated image about real data, text that highlighted is exactly 75 characters, same as others

Comment: Should have probably considered the nodejs version used before submitting answers!

Comment: Javascript strings are stored in UTF16, so each character takes two bytes.  5 million strings of 75 characters would be 750 MB, and the join has to create another 750 MB.  The lesson is, you will need to find another way.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js has a maximum (single) string length of [about 1GB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length#description) on 64-bit system, or about half that on 32-bit systems. When you run into this limit, the error shown is exactly the one that you're getting.

To reproduce the issue, here's a small script:

```
const str = '*'.repeat(108);
const arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
  arr.push(str);
}
arr.join('');
```

If you replace `108` with `107`, it doesn't crash. It's not entirely clear why you're running into the same issue with only 75 characters per item, but I'm still pretty sure that this is your problem.

To fix it, either write the contents of `game_res` to the file in batches, or open the output file before the loop and write each item to the file directly from the loop.

Comment: i tested your code, replace 108 with 107, still give me error at 5,000,000 amount sir

Comment: Might depend on the Node.js version that you're using, or which platform you're using. Anyway, that's just secondary to what your issue is and how to fix it.

Comment: i try replace 107 with 1 at 5,000,000 amount this time it said `<--- Last few GCs ---> last resort GC in old space requested` and `<--- JS stacktrace ---> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

Comment: What type of system are you running this on? If it can't even handle strings of that size without running into memory issues it's woefully underpowered.

Comment: my pc spec: i7 9700 + 16gb ram, windows 10 pro 64 bit

Comment: Doesn't really make sense then.

Comment: problem solved sir, i just updated node.js from 14.17.0-x86 to node-v16.17.1-x64 and it works fine